# How to fill in NaN values within the same column, with a minimal value of a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to fill in NaN values within the same column, with a minimal value of a group - see below df and df2. For category '2' in column 'A' I want to have min(20, 15)...help please :)

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4], 
               "B": [ np.nan , 10, np.nan, 20, 15, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,40, np.nan]})

In[1]: df
Out[1]: 
    A     B
0   1   NaN
1   1  10.0
2   2   NaN
3   2  20.0
4   2  15.0
5   3   NaN
6   3   NaN
7   3   NaN
8   3   NaN
9   4  40.0
10  4   NaN
```

## How to obtain df2, without a loop - ?

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4], 
               "B": [ 10 , 10, 15, 15, 15, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,40, 40]})

In[1]: df2
Out[18]: 
A     B
0   1  10.0
1   1  10.0
2   2  15.0
3   2  15.0
4   2  15.0
5   3   NaN
6   3   NaN
7   3   NaN
8   3   NaN
9   4  40.0
10  4  40.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want replace all values by `min` per groups use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('min')
print (df)
    A     B
0   1  10.0
1   1  10.0
2   2  15.0
3   2  15.0
4   2  15.0
5   3   NaN
6   3   NaN
7   3   NaN
8   3   NaN
9   4  40.0
10  4  40.0
```

If want replace only `NaN`s to `min` add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or use custom lambda  function:

```
df['B'] = df.B.fillna(df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('min'))
```

Alternative:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.min()))

print (df)
    A     B
0   1  10.0
1   1  10.0
2   2  15.0
3   2  20.0
4   2  15.0
5   3   NaN
6   3   NaN
7   3   NaN
8   3   NaN
9   4  40.0
10  4  40.0
```

Answer (score 2):

As an experiment, I wanted to see if I could do this with Numpy.  This isn't perfect as it doesn't handle negative values, or zeros for that matter.  I could change it to do so but nonetheless, here is the prototype.

```
b = df.B.values
a = df.A.values

a_, u_ = pd.factorize(a)
_a = a_.max() - a_

maxb = np.nanmax(b)

basis_inc = a_ * maxb
basis_dec = _a * maxb
bnan = np.isnan(b)
bfill_zero = np.where(bnan, maxb + 1, b)

ffill_min = np.minimum.accumulate(bfill_zero + basis_dec) - basis_dec
bfill_min = np.minimum.accumulate((bfill_zero + basis_inc)[::-1])[::-1] - basis_inc

gmin = np.minimum(ffill_min, bfill_min)
df.assign(B=np.where(bnan & (gmin != maxb + 1), gmin, b))

    A     B
0   1  10.0
1   1  10.0
2   2  15.0
3   2  20.0
4   2  15.0
5   3   NaN
6   3   NaN
7   3   NaN
8   3   NaN
9   4  40.0
10  4  40.0
```

Comment: @jezrael fixed.  That was fun.